# PayPal Sandbox issue with WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using WooCommerce and PayPal in sandbox mode. When I place an order it shows me a success message at the end of the sandbox, but in WooCommerce, I get the message "Pending payment".

I have tried everything that is on google but not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Probably an IPN issue, with the IPN endpoint not accepting connections from PayPal.

You can use the following to check your IPN history for the sandbox receiver account: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Make sure you're using the latest PayPal Checkout plugin for WooCommerce, it may not depend on IPN: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/